# I installed my Inky Phat on top of my Speaker phat, but it's not working

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite

So i did every `curl get.pimoroni.com/blahblah` and everything seems to be working. BUT my Inky Phat is not working at all. But my speaker phat is working well ! I'm using a ZeroW, I tried over multiples PS (3A, 5.1V/2.5 and 1A)

I double checked the pinout :

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/inky_phat

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/speaker_phat

But I really don't understand. I did test over a RPi-3B+ to see if my solderings are not good, but it fails...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Does the Inky work without stacking on the speaker phat?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I needed to put it on another Pi, so it refreshes the screen, and AFTER that, I can put it back on the Speaker phat, really strange tho

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.